# issue in using tooltip in scatter plot through mpld3 in ipython and Spark

Tags: python, matplotlib, apache-spark, scatter-plot, mpld3

I have a `RDD` which has studentid and their scores:

```
Student_record = data.map(lambda x:x[0]).zip(score)
```

I then display the scores on a `scatter plot` using `mpld3`.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpld3

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(1,score.count()+1,1)

ax.scatter(x, predict, c='red', s=100, alpha=0.4)
ax.grid(color='lightgray', alpha=0.7)
ax.set_ylabel("score")
ax.set_xlabel("student")
mpld3.display(fig)
```

What I have been trying to do is to include a `tooltip` functionality such that when my mouse hovers over a particular score point on the plot it shows the studentid whose score it is. I was going through [this](http://mpld3.github.io/examples/scatter_tooltip.html) documentation, which uses `tooltip` to shows that when the mouse hovers over a point it displays the point number, but I am having difficulty in understanding how to do it in my case. How can I get this hover functionality added to my current code?

Answer (score 1):

The [Scatter Plot With Tooltips example](http://mpld3.github.io/examples/scatter_tooltip.html) seems like just the thing for you.  Just change the last line from `mpld3.show()` to `mpld3.display()` to get it inline in the IPython notebook.